# Can I populate LDAP accounts using a table of username/passwords from a different database?

Tags: ldap, crm

Our users' web passwords/usernames/firstname/lastname/etc are in the dbo.contacts table in our CRM. This is great for CRM and our CRM compatible apps, but I would love to query these accounts with software that can only query LDAP.

Is it possible to tell openldap, "Hey, create logins using this table*" and to update this information periodically as obviously information changes over time? My scripting-fu isn't very strong but I've worked with php and webservices and would just like to get ldap talking to this table so I can get serious with single-sign-on.

Thanks.

*This can be a live connection to the CRM db via odbc/ado, a csv file, or connection via webservices.

Comment: Also I may be looking at this problem the wrong way. LDAP would be nice but I think I can get away with Shibboleth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with OpenLDAP. LDAP clients can use the add request to add entries, assuming the client's authorization state allows adding users under the base object chosen by client. There is a standalone modify client called `ldapmodify`. Please ["LDAP: Mastering ldapmodify"](http://ff1959.wordpress.com/2011/07/25/master-the-ldapmodify-command-line-tool/) for more information.

Be aware that the some versions of the openldap ldapmodify tool are broken in that it incorrectly allows values with trailing spaces (which is illegal). The directory server base 64 encodes these values, which is probably not what was intended.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'll play with the ldapmodify client.